# How to exclude the datagridviewtextboxcolumn from edit mode?

Tags: c#, windows, datagridviewtextboxcell, editmode

I have a grid view of type datagridviewtextboxcolumn with the  following fields:

```
 SrNo    |   Description   |    HSNCode   |    Qty   |    Rate    |    Amount
```

The SrNo and the Amount are calculated automatically from the code and both are in `ReadOnly` mode.I want the  user to edit when he enters the cell. For that I have set the edit mode of the grid in `Page_Load()` event of the form.

```
grdData.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
```

But the logic of generating the SrNo. and Amount does not work when I set the EditMode in this way. Which way can i use to apply the edit mode on all columns excluding these two columns.(SrNo. & Amount).I have used the `CellEnter()` event of the grid view to generate the "SrNo" and "Amount" in my program.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can set  the **ReadOnly** property of that particular columns instead of using the **EditMode** property of grid.

You can configure the ReadOnly property to **True** of columns using columns designer dialog window.

Hope this helps